# impala partitions with < or > conditions

Tags: cloudera, impala

I have 2TB of cell phone records, about 33 billion readings of 1.8 million users.
I have created a partition on the user id.
Impala creates many sub-directories called `userid=XXXXX`.
This seems like over partitioning with 1.8 million sub-dirs. Is there a way to have to have partitions with a range or array of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Impala does not have any sort of range partitioning. So You will need to partition on a different column in your table that would create fewer partitions. Or as a workaround you could add an additional column to your table which stores the specified range you want for each record and then partition on the "range" column. Example: You have a record with a field user_id=1234 which would then also have a field of your range user_range=0_100000, which you could use for partitioning.